# jQuery make injected option select by default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of selects that I unfortunately have to inject an option called 'please select' into as the first option. I then want to make the 'please select' in all selects on the page, selected. As I can't change the HTML, this is my only choice.

However, my code seems to be only making the first select's 'please select' selected.

HTML:

```
<select name="" id="" class="cartDdlOptions">
  <option value="1">Some Value</option>
  <option value="2">Some Value</option>
  <option value="3">Some Value</option>
  <option value="4">Some Value</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="" class="cartDdlOptions">
  <option value="1">Some Value</option>
  <option value="2">Some Value</option>
  <option value="3">Some Value</option>
  <option value="4">Some Value</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="" class="cartDdlOptions">
  <option value="1">Some Value</option>
  <option value="2">Some Value</option>
  <option value="3">Some Value</option>
  <option value="4">Some Value</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){


  $('.cartDdlOptions').prepend('<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>');
  var selectOperator = $(".cartDdlOptions option").eq(0);

  $(".cartDdlOptions").each(function(){

    if (selectOperator.val() == ""){
      console.log(selectOperator);
      selectOperator.attr("selected", true); 
    }

  });

});
```

[Working example.](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/FpskA)

Really can't work this one out. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `var selectOperator = $(".cartDdlOptions option").eq(0);` will only give you the **first** matching select's first option, but you have multiple selects.

Comment: Ahh.. This must be my mistake, I couldnt work out why the first was the only one being affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it that with just two lines instead of writing much code this way:

```
$(".cartDdlOptions").each(function(){

      $(this).prepend('<option value="0" selected>Please Select</option>'); //add please select option
      $(this).val("0") // set it as selected


  });
```

If you don't want to set **value** attribute then you can do as @T.J Cowder pointed:

```
$(".cartDdlOptions").each(function () {

    $(this).prepend('<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>'); //add please select option
    $(this).val("") // set it as selected

});
```

### EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/cqrs2g8w/

Comment: Since he's adding it with `value=""`, presumably he...wants the value to be `""`, not `"0"`. (But `val("")` should work.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes you are right but i am just shortening the code that it can be done with just two lines instead of writing so many lines to achieve this

Comment: That's irrelevant (and this is definitely the better way). There's no need to change his value, just use the value he's using.

Comment: Also note that your fiddle is misleading (even though, again, your answer is in broad terms the right way to do this), because there are two reasons the first option will be selected *anyway* (you could just remove the `val` call entirely): First, the markup being inserted has `selected` in it, and second it's the first option which will get defaulted anyway. But something like this, where we remove those two factors, proves `val` is working (with `""` as the value): http://jsfiddle.net/cqrs2g8w/1/

Comment: This works a treat. I totally over complicated things. Thank you :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder totally agreed, but i used to add -1 as value in the default case as in asp.net we have `SelectedIndex` -1 so i feel comfrotable that way